# How to redirect a command with parameters in bash?

Tags: bash, rpm

I want to output "hello" when `rpm -qf /etc/redhat-release` is typed. 
Otherwise rpm should work as it would normally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't seem overly useful, but a function would do the trick:

```
rpm() {
  if [ "$1" = "-qf" ] && [ "$2" = "/etc/redhat-release" ]
  then
    echo hello
  else
    command rpm "$@"
  fi
}
```